# Getting info out of gklocalplayer (email nickname)

Tags: ios, iphone, gamekit

I am building a game where I use the serves of Apple in combination of my own server and I wand to get the e-mail info of the local user and the nickname

Answer (score 1):

The nickname (Alias) can be got by using

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
```

and then

```
NSSTring *userName = [localPlayer alias];
```

That's it, I'm not sure if you're supposed to get users' email and cache it on your server without their consent, i'm not even sure if apple gives out user Emails.

the only way I would do it is to ask the user for the email using an alert !